# fancy chapter heading for a book

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters, fncychap

I would like to change the default chapter heading formatting of `book` document class.

How can I output something like below :

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the package [fncychap](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fncychap)

Comment: Also see some of the chapter style offered by [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) - **6.5.1 Defining a chapter style**, p 83.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel thanks a lot. Can you write this as an answer so that I can accept it as answer.

Comment: Have a look at Vincent Zoonekynd's impressive on line selection of [chapter heading](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html) and [section heading](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_section/0.html) designs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To modify the header of a chapter you can use on of the predefined styles of the package [`fncychap`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fncychap)

In relation to your question I present a small example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Compiler Construction Tools}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

As [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) mentioned you can also use the [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class which also provides some styles. Examples can be found in the documentation of [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) (6.5.1 Defining a chapter style, p 83.)

Comment: t's great as a result, however, I have a question:
how to put the title in the interior of framework

Comment: @Labaïr: At the moment I can't test. I would recommend to aks a new question which linked to this one.