# Command for \part style output and little abstract

Tags: macros, parts

I am new in this forum and I am kind of novice in LaTeX. I would like to know how to make this presentation as macro in order to change the **PART** (here chapter, I am using \documentclass{article}) output title style, like this : [image: Chapterstyle]
And just after, I want a little rectangle (that can be a different command of course) with the margins bigger only here with text, like a little abstract with the first letter bigger :
[image: Rectintro]
Thanks a lot, Pierre

Comment: This looks like the `Lenny` chapter style from [`fncychap`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fncychap)...

Comment: See [Fancy chapter heading for a book](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32446/5764).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The only problem is that I actually use ARTICLE and I can't change it because of some packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \@makechapterhead{\textsc{#2}}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip 3ex
    \@afterheading}
\def\@spart#1{%
     \@makeschapterhead{\textsc{#1}}%
     \nobreak
     \vskip 3ex
     \@afterheading}
\newcommand\@chapapp{\textsc{\partname}}
\newcommand\thechapter{\arabic{part}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\part{test}
test
\part{test}
test
\end{document}
```

**Complete code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \@makechapterhead{\textsc{#2}}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip 3ex
    \@afterheading}
\def\@spart#1{%
     \@makeschapterhead{\textsc{#1}}%
     \nobreak
     \vskip 3ex
     \@afterheading}
\newcommand\@chapapp{\textsc{\partname}}
\newcommand\thechapter{\arabic{part}}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.8}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{partabstract}{%
\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, width=.8\textwidth, arc=0pt,
             colback=shadecolor, colframe=shadecolor]}{%
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}}


\begin{document}

\part{test} 

\begin{partabstract}
\lettrine[lines=3,slope=-4pt,nindent=0pt]{D}{ans} ce chapitre
\lipsum[1]
\end{partabstract}

\lipsum[1-2]

\part{test}
test
\end{document}
```

if you want part start in new page like book's chapter add this

```
\renewcommand\part{\clearpage
                \thispagestyle{plain}%
                \global\@topnum\z@
                \@afterindentfalse
                \secdef\@part\@spart}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is exactly what I wanted. Thumbs up